Too many warnings after running npx create-expo-app
Whenever I run npx create-expo-app I get a lot of warnings and I want to understand why, I'm using ubuntu, the lastest lts node version (20.12.2) and trying to create a new react native app.


What's your question here? "Why do I get these warnings?" Because the libraries you're using are depending on these things that are now deprecated. "Do I need to care about these particular warnings?" No, you don't.

Thank you. Yes, I was wondering if I had to care about these warnings, so now I see it is something that react native has to solve

Expo isn't React Native...
